# How to delete a row, having string which start with a white space?

Tags: r, stringr

my dataset is like the following

```
John
Tally
 mac
hero
```

I want to delete the string which start with " "

so the resulting variable would be

```
John
Tally
hero
```

I have used

```
library(stringr)
which(startsWith(names[,1]," "))
```

to get the rows having " "

Please help me any efficient way to delete this ?

Comment: `startsWith` comes from `gdata` not `stringr`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way with `regex` and `grepl`:

```
vec <- c('John',
         'Tally',
         ' mac',
         'hero')

 #grepl returns TRUE if there is a match.
 #'^ ' is regex for 'starting with space'
  > vec[!grepl('^ ', vec)]
[1] "John"  "Tally" "hero"
```

Or as per @NealFultz 's comment:

```
> vec[grep('^ ', vec, invert=TRUE)]
[1] "John"  "Tally" "hero"

> grep('^ ', vec, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)
[1] "John"  "Tally" "hero"
```

Or if you want to use `startsWith`:

```
library(gdata)
#notice the minus sign below just before which
> vec[-which(startsWith(vec," "))]
[1] "John"  "Tally" "hero"
```

or simply (as per @Gregor 's comment):

```
> vec[!startsWith(vec, " ")]
[1] "John"  "Tally" "hero"
```

Comment: See also `grep(..., invert=TRUE)`

Comment: np. See also `grep(..., value=TRUE)` and you can get it down to one function call.

Comment: It's these details in the documentation that sometimes you don't read because you know an alternative :P. thanks again!

Comment: Also, which is unnecessary, `vec[!startsWith(vec, " ")]`

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for this, I just copied the OP's function and ran it to be honest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`:

```
> vec[!str_detect(vec, "^\\s")]
# [1] "John"  "Tally" "hero"
```

Using `stringi`:

```
> vec[!stri_detect(vec, regex = "^\\s")]
# [1] "John"  "Tally" "hero"
```